# Abusing C# 6.0's new interpolated strings

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

I think the interpolated strings from C# 6.0 are by far the most practical. However, what's the point of using interpolation if your string looks like this:

```
string str0 = $"{chatType + prefix + group + name} > {message}";
```

How would you format this? As you can see I use C#'s string interpolation along with the concat symbol '+', which looks a bit odd.

Also, could someone explain me when one would abuse this feature, for example:

```
static string str1 = $"{str2}:"
```

Rather than:

```
static string str2 = str1 + ":"
```

Comment: What about interpolated strings in interpolated strings?

Comment: I hope this is no sarcasm, because it sounds odder.

Comment: It was an attempt to be amusing. And yes, it is possible to put a string interpolation in a string interpolation.

Comment: Just use whatever reads better and is more obvious to "future you" reading the code in 6 months time. Unless this lies at the heart of a mission critical loop, it really doesn't matter. I'm sure you'll find plenty of **opinions**, but at the end of the day, it's your choice. Just be aware of the implications. Here's a fun read: https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/

Comment: Well, those oscillating jokes got me no further in my inquiry of knowledge.

Comment: The point is using whatever you think is most clear and concise: interpolation, concatenation or a plain old `String.Format`. As with all features, it can be used in ways that you might not consider most clear and concise -- "abuse" is a subjective term. (Then there's the people who will jump on the performance of this and that, but that's almost always premature optimization -- optimizing string handling globally when it becomes a bottleneck is typically a bit more involved than just using one form or another.)

Answer (score 2):

The format would be:

```
string str0 = $"{chatType}{prefix}{group}{name} > {message}";
```

As far as I'm aware, the benefit of interpolated strings or string.Format is supposed to be in memory usage. When you add a string to a string, a new string is created in memory. So:

```
string x = a + b + c + d;
```

Creates a string for a + b, creates a string for that plus c and another for that + d. So three strings have been created in memory where only one was required.

The obvious benefit for me is that it looks nicer and neater, you don't get double quotes all over the place, it's easier to see what the resulting string will look like. It's just a nicer way to use string.format.

Comment: Ah yes. Unfortunately, this is fake news. :) I just spent a bit of time reading the compiler generated IL because this was my suspicion, but I was proved wrong. Actually, with `string x = a + b + c + d;`... each parameter gets loaded into a temporary array, then `string.Concat` is called over the array. About as efficient as you might hope for.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2013/06/17/string-concatenation-behind-the-scenes-part-one/

Comment: It's more of an issue when multiple const strings are involved (text in quotes) as part of the expression.

Comment: And if you're adding to a string on multiple lines. You should use stringbuilder